# How to stop sending requests to dispatch_async requests for ringing?

Tags: objective-c

I click the button to beep and as the background thread there is a welcome message appears on the view controller, the beep is continuously going on until i close the application. 
How can i suspend the queue for further execution when welcome message arrives on the view controller?

I tried  calling from another view controller `dispatch_suspend(dispatch_get_main_queue());` when welcome screen comes in but the beep is continuously going on in background. Can somebody have hint to stop queue from executing or just clean the queue?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSInteger timeintervalForBeep;
    if (_bu.buModel == BuTwo) {
        timeintervalForBeep = 7; 
    } else {
        timeintervalForBeep = 2;
    }

    _findBeepTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeintervalForBeep 
                                                      target:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(makeBeep) 
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    // Fire it once immediately.
    [_findBeepTimer fire];
});
```

Comment: Call [_findBeepTimer invalidate]; in your makeBeep method. Btw, since you fire it immediately, your timer is useless: why didn't you update the view immediately? Creating a timer and firing it it is the same as calling the method.

Comment: I have [_findBeepTimer invalidate] in the stop button, but when the welcome screen comes up i dont have option to cancel it as the view controller is changed and beep is going on in the background. But normally i start it with a button and end with a button it works fine for me.

Comment: I suggest you to add more code: you just posted the start of the timer while the problem seems in the idea behind the architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the makeBeep function, invalidate the timer by adding the following codes:

```
[_findBeepTimer invalidate];
_findBeepTimer = nil;
```

Comment: I have [_findBeepTimer invalidate] in the stop button, but when the welcome screen comes up i dont have option to cancel it as the view controller is changed and beep is going on in the background. But normally i start it with a button and end with a button it works fine for me.

Comment: try making an nsnotification to the other viewcontroller and stop it there